# Проблема то ли с позиционированием метода, то ли что-то ещё

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 3;
        int m = 10;
        int n1 = 0;
        int m1 = 0;
        string[,] buddyBook = new string[n, m];
        int [,] sort_directive = new int[n1, m1];


        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BuddyBook!\nInput E to enter Menu\nInput X to exit");
        string ans = Console.ReadLine();
        string [] ema = new string [100];
        string [] num = new string [100];
        string [] org = new string [100];
        if ((ans == "E") || (ans == "e"))
        {
            while((ans != "X") || (ans != "x"))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("1. Print BuddyBook:\n\t(A) Ascending order\n\t(B) Descending order\n2. Add Buddy\n3. Delete Buddy\n4. Update Buddy\n5. Search Buddy\n\t(A) Name\n\t(B) Phone number\n6. Exit");
                ans = Console.ReadLine();
                if ((ans == "X") || (ans == "x")){Console.WriteLine("See you soon!"); break;}
                switch (ans)
                {
                    case "1":
                        bookAdd();
                        break;

                    case "8":
                        return;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("No such option here, try again\n");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        void bookAdd(){
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Enter name: "); 
        }
    }
}
```

Это псевдо-обрезок кода всего проекта

---

*После предложения поставить `static` перед `bookAdd`:*

Вот сама ошибка:

> Feature 'static local functions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please
>   use language version 8.0 or greater.

Comment: Сейчас я минус поставлю Вам. За такой вопрос.

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: Ну черно по белому написано причина проблемы и как ее исправить.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Приятель рассказал о политике и правилах сайта, впредь формулировку постараюсь привести в порядок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Program
{

  public static void Main()
  {
    ...
  }

  static void bookAdd()
  {
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Enter name: "); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Так в эмуляторе не поддерживается статика, ругается на версию шарпа, мол 8.0 стоит, а вы пишите на старом.

Comment: @HZITS Я не понимаю, о чем Вы говорите. Кто-то уже поставил минус Вам.

Comment: Вот сама ошибка:Feature 'static local functions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater. ~dotnetfiddle.com
На минус мне всё равно, ошибка требует срочного решения, поэтому и наверное не могу сформулировать вопрос правильно.

Comment: @HZITS У Вас функция `bookAdd` случайно попала внутрь функции `Main`.